# Using pd.update to update only a slice of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large `pandas` dataframe where I am attempting to use the `update` function to bring some data from a second dataframe. However I only want the first dataframe's values to update if they are nulls. If there's already a value there, I want to keep the original value.

I thought this would be pretty straightforward: use `.loc` and `isnull()` to limit where `update` was operating, then use `map` to bring over the data from the second df. However this method doesn't do a darn thing.

The MRE below uses a `for` loop to accomplish what I want. Specifically, it should turn all of the `NaN` in 'Year' to 2021. Right above that is the code I attempted that doesn't do anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sp = ['Ross', 'Rachel', 'Joey', 'Monica', 'Chandler', 'Phoebe']
sp = sorted(sp * 36)
yrs = list(range(2017, 2020))
years = sorted(yrs * 12)
years = years * 6
months = list(range(1, 13))
months = months * 18

df_data = {'SalesPerson': sp,
            'Year': years,
            'Month': months,
            'Sales':np.random.randint(20, 50, 216)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)

df.loc[(df['SalesPerson'] == 'Ross') &
        (df['Year'] == 2017), 'Year'] = np.nan

temp_df = df.loc[df['SalesPerson'] =='Ross', 'Year'].copy()
temp_df['Year'] = 2021
merge_dict = dict(zip(temp_df.index, temp_df['Year']))

#WHY DOESN'T UPDATE WORK FOR MY PURPOSE?
#df.loc[df['Year'].isnull(), 'Year'].update(df.index.map(merge_dict))
#df.update(df[df['Year'].isnull()].index.map(merge_dict))

for k in merge_dict.keys():
    if pd.isnull(df.loc[k, 'Year']):
        df.loc[k, 'Year'] = merge_dict[k]

print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? what would be the output for the salesperson whose name is Ross?

Comment: All the NaN's should be replaced with the same-index value from temp_df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pandas.Series.combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html). The result is union of the two series that is in case of `Null` value in **`caller series`**, the value from **`passed series`** is taken.

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].combine_first(temp_df['Year'])
```

Comment: Both this and @peter-curran 's solutions work great. I'm picking this one because it is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `pd.DataFrame` as you temp_df rather than a `pd.Series` it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sp = ['Ross', 'Rachel', 'Joey', 'Monica', 'Chandler', 'Phoebe']
sp = sorted(sp * 36)
yrs = list(range(2017, 2020))
years = sorted(yrs * 12)
years = years * 6
months = list(range(1, 13))
months = months * 18

df_data = {'SalesPerson': sp,
            'Year': years,
            'Month': months,
            'Sales':np.random.randint(20, 50, 216)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)


# creates incomplete dataframe
df.loc[(df['SalesPerson'] == 'Ross') &
        (df['Year'] == 2017), 'Year'] = np.nan

df.to_csv("test.csv")


# creates complete dataframe for Ross, with index matching main df
other = df.loc[(df['SalesPerson'] =='Ross') &
                 (df['Year'].isnull())]
other['Year'] = 2021

df.update(other)
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

Comment: This works fine. Picked @shradha 's answer because it is simpler, but I think in some use cases, this answer would be useful.